# tableView cell returning NULL

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to read the text from a tableView cell and in the prepareForSegue method, I would take the text and set it to NSUserDefaults. However, when I NSLog the text, it returns NULL. 
This is what I've tried.

```
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(UITableViewCell *)sender
      {
         NSString *blah = sender.textLabel.text;
         NSLog(@"%@",blah); // It returns NULL no matter what cell is clicked
      }
```

Comment: Are you sure the `sender` is a `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: Yes, I got the row using      int row = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender].row;

Comment: Views shouldn't own data. You should be able to use the row to ask the model for the data.

Comment: @paul.s Any chance you know how? I've been stuck on this for a while now. I've tried using - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath and saving the row's text in NSUserDefaults, but when I try to get it in the prepareForSegue method, it's still NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use the label from the cell, because it is part of the view. Although the cell is correct, its visuals may be disposed by the time the `prepareForSegue:` is called.

The MVC way of doing this would be querying the underlying data source for the data at the cell's row, and use that data instead of the label.

Here is what I mean: somewhere in the implementation of `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you have code that looks like this:

```
NSString *labelData = [myDataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = labelData;
```

You should replicate that code inside your `prepareForSegue:` method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(UITableViewCell *)sender
{
    NSUInteger row = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender].row
    NSString *labelData = [myDataSource objectAtIndex:row];
    NSLog(@"%@", labelData); // This should work
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method you will be assigning the `cell.textLabel.text` to something based on the `indexPath`.

This could look something like

```
id myDomainObject = [self objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.textLabel.text = myDomainObject.text;
```

So if you can get the indexPath in the prepareForSegue you can get your domain object and from there you can get the text.

Without seeing your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` I can't give much more advice